# Auth0 React SPA incorrect access token for API

Tags: reactjs, jwt, auth0

So I have read through several SO questions about this, and read many Auth0 tutorials on this, but I still cannot get the Access Token to work with my custom API.

I have followed the Auth0 SPA tutorial for React.
I then followed the "Call Your API from Your Single-Page App" tutorial. 
I have created an "auth0-authorization-extension-api". 
I enabled API access to my custom API.

I feel I have done the necessary steps, but I feel I am missing how to request the proper access token from my React client.

My Axios custom hook contains the following code inside a useEffect:

```
const send = async () => {
  try {
    await getTokenSilently().then(async (token: string) => {
      const config = {
        method: method as "GET" | "POST",
        withCredentials: true,
        data: providedData,
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + token
        }
      };
      const result = await axios(address + uri, config);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    if (!canceled) {
      dispatch({ type: "FETCH_FAILURE" });
    }
  }
};
```

The access token being sent to my API is not a full jwt, but a string of numbers and letters approximately 35 digits in length.

Every time I get the error `UnauthorizedError: jwt malformed` from my custom API.

My audience for the React SPA is `http://localhost:3000`, and the API audience is `http://localhost:8080`.

Am I missing something simple here or am I looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The access token you got is just a pure random string.
With Auth0, if you want to a JWT as access token, you have to [indicate the audience](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react/02-calling-an-api#specify-the-api-audience) i.e. the API identifier.